# Prove diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ matrices over $\Bbb C$. Assume that $AB=BA$ and that $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Show that $B$ is diagonalizable.

I am thinking of using $QBQ^{-1}=\Lambda$, which means that $B$ needs to have $n$ distinct eigenvalues, is this correct? Could somebody give me some hints.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue of $\lambda$.  Then $A(B \vec{v}) = B(A \vec{v}) = \lambda B \vec{v}$.  Thus $B \vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.  Therefore $B \vec{v}$ is a multiple of $\vec{v}$ (why?).  Hence, if $\vec{v}_1, \dots, \vec{v}_n$ in a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$, from the previous observation it is also a basis consisting of eigenvectors of $B$, so $B$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

Having $Av_s=\lambda_sv_s$ for $s=1,...,n$ with all $\lambda_s$ different, then $$ABv_s=BAv_s=\lambda_sBv_s$$ implies that we have $Bv_s$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with the same $\lambda_s$ eigenvalue, then $Bv_s$ is in the $\lambda_s$-eigenspace generated by $v_s$, then $Bv_s=\mu_sv_s$ for some $\mu_s$, all different, so
$B$ has $n$-different eigenvectors and $B$ also diagonalizable.